# Having trouble with, switch case and if Statements-Arduino

Tags: loops

I am trying to write a sketch for a device that measures engine running time and logs it to a sd card
there are 4 conditions that are needed: Note one digital input called engine pin
Conditions and response;   1-engine pin HIGH && lastState LOW
print engine Running and time in seconds.    2-engine  pin HIGH && lastState HIGH
do nothing and continue.    3-engine pin LOW && lastState HIGH  print time in seconds and engine Off
4-engine pin LOW && lastState LOW  do nothing and continue there are a few more steps that happen
after this

I know how to send the time stamps to the sd, I'am using secondsTime and  that seems to work
I can supply more info, but this is my first question and I am not sure how this should be posted
thanks for your time

I tried using if and else statements and switch case but it seems like either it would not compile
or it would compile but not function, I tried very hard to get the curly braces right and structure
but I am a beginner and I just cant seem to work it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a truly basic programming question but we all had to start from somewhere :-)

There is a million of ways of formulating an if statement that you need.
For something like this I would have as the first IF test the state of the engine pins (HIGH or LOW) and then go deeper.

Your case is quite simple as you only have 2 variables and each can only have 2 states HIGH/LOW so you can use simple IF...else only checking for one condition and if it's not than it must be the other.
Also, logically you have two conditions that when true you don't have to do anything (engine was running and is still running / engine was off and still is off) which you can possibly disregard completely.

Here's an example

```
int enginePin = 1; // whatever the engine pin is
int lastState = LOW; //start with engine off

void setup(){
   pinMode(enginePin,INPUT);
}

void loop(){
  
  
   int currentState = digitalRead(enginePin); // let's grab the current state of the engine

   if(currentState == HIGH){ //the engine is on

      if(lastState == LOW){

         // the engine was not running before but it is now, that means that it has just started
         // print "Running" and whatever else you need

      }else{ //lastState is HIGH, you can potentially completely remove this else statement
          // do nothing, the engine is still running
      }

   }else{ // it's LOW

      if(lastState == HIGH){

         //the engine has just now stopped running
         // print "OFF" and whatever else you need

      }else{ //lastState is LOW, you can potentially completely remove this else statement
         // do nothing, is still off

      }

  }

   lastState = currentState; //let's remember what the engine state was

}
```

Ans here is the same thing without comments and ignoring the checks that you may not need, so it may be easier for you to visualise

```
void loop(){
  
  
   int currentState = digitalRead(enginePin);

   if(currentState == HIGH){
      if(lastState == LOW){
         //engine started
      }

   }else{
      if(lastState == HIGH){
         //engine stopped
      }

  }

   lastState = currentState;

}
```

That's it, hope this helps

Comment: I have tested your sketch with a few print commands and it works flawlessly, I Really had over thought the process, You really coded it well and understood what I was trying to do

Comment: Thank you! Oh, and you actually haven't overthought the process enough, I have :-)

Comment: I am still having trouble getting this to print or log to SD, if I serial print the engine on time and the engine off time it works fine, when I change it to print to the SD it throws the scope off I think, I am having issues with if statements any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: I would need to see your full code as it could be a anything. You should start a completely new question and leave me a message with the link to the question here . Don't add more to this question here as it could be confusing to others.

Comment: Thankyou for the help, I am going to try Logging to the onboard EEprom as I found some limitations to Using the SD Card, for my Project if I have trouble I will message you